# Definition of $\exp(A)$ in terms of spectral decomposition.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, exponential-function

I am read this question [Plugging a matrix multiplied by an imaginary number in the exponential function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107808/plugging-a-matrix-multiplied-by-an-imaginary-number-in-the-exponential-function). Here the question'author defined $$\exp(A) := \sum_{1\le k\le n}\exp(\lambda_k) P_k$$

What reference contain this definition "exp is defined in terms of the spectral decomposition"?

Comment: What you are claiming works for a diagonalizable matrix. And only then. A visual way to see how $\exp (A)$ is then defined is to write it $A=P^{-1}DP$ with $D$ diagonal. Then $\exp A=P^{-1}(\exp D)P$. And it is easy to see what $\exp D$ should be.

Comment: So, let me guess your question.  Usually, this equation is a theorem.  But you want a reference where this equation is used as the definition?

Comment: Why $\exp A=P^{-1}(\exp D)P$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why $\exp A=P^{−1}(\exp D)P$?

Because plugging $A=P^{-1}DP$ into 
$$\exp A=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} A^n \tag1$$
and simplifying $(P^{-1}DP)^n = P^{-1}D^n P$, one obtains
$$\exp A=P^{-1}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} D^n \right) P = P^{−1}(\exp D)P \tag2$$